# Delete folders and files from many subfolders

Tags: windows, file, directory, subdirectory

I have this structure - main folder with many subfolders (names for example only):

Mainfolder

|-subfoldernamea

|-subfoldernameb

|...

|-subfoldernamez

each subfolder have folders and files.

I need to delete folders and files (older than 1 month) in each subfolder.

It is possible to create simple cmd script, or i need manually write all subfolders names in script?

Comment: Is this microsoft windows or some other OS? Although you said cmd script so I assume windows. I ask because you should add some tags about your OS and preferred scripting.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2